# Swift iOS not setting "If-None-Match" header tag

Tags: ios, swift, caching, afnetworking, etag

I can't get swift to set the "If-None-Match" header field after it received a previous response with an etag value.

**Example Swift code**:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

func singleRequest(callback: (Void -> Void)?) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
        (response, data, error) in
        callback?()
    })
}

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()

singleRequest({
    singleRequest({
    })
})
```

**Example nodeJS server**:

```
var http = require('http');

  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'ETag':  '"075ced9bfb821b8d2d372ec9fccf95d1c"', 'Cache-Control' : 'private'});
    res.end('Your node.js server is running on localhost:3000');

}).listen(3000);
```

Looking at the requests in Wireshark shows, that neither has a "If-None-Match" header field set. I would expect the second request to take the ETag value from the first response.

I tried explicitly setting a URLCache with

```
let URLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 4 * 1024 * 1024, diskCapacity: 20 * 1024 * 1024, diskPath: nil)
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(URLCache)
```

and using NSURLSession, AFNetworking or AlamoFire instead of NSURLConnection. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: You have to add these in the request header explicitly and issue a HEAD request to check if the requested resource has changed at the server.  Yo You can take a look at my FileDownloader project to see how this is done for files(we need to cache the ETag, and Last-Modified, ourselves): https://github.com/shripada/FileDownloader.git